# Android Studio 2.3 removes module references

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

I have an Android project, consisting of multiple modules. *I do not use Gradle*.

With Android 2.2.3 the project worked well, but I updated my Android Studio to 2.3.

When I loaded the *main* project, I got this message:

```
Update Property Files
The structure of following Android modules was changed:
ActionbarSherlock
```

I checked my repository to see what has changed in the main project, and in in my project config, I found the following.

These line were removed:

```
# This file is automatically generated by IntelliJ IDEA
# Project target.
target=android-16
android.library.reference.1=../ActionbarSherlock
android.library.reference.2=../WizarDroid
```

And this line is added:

```
# This file is automatically generated by IntelliJ IDEA
# Project target.
target=android-16
project.type=0
```

In the module dependencies, I still can see the module, yet I get compile errors:

```
D:\MainProject\res\values\styles.xml:51: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light'.

D:\MainProject\res\values\styles.xml:53: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarTabStyle'.
```

What can I do about that?

UPDATE:

I could not make it work with 2.3, so I reverted back to 2.2.3.
Now, when my project is compiled and run, it crashes with the following errors:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
```

On the message dialog, it shows a completely different text instead of the OK text. It really messed up my project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I had to revert back to 2.2.3 and add the modules again.**

I guess, in 2.3 only Gradle is safe...